# Exact sequence of Riemann-Roch spaces and adeles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, function-fields

I am studying Riemann-Roch theorem on the book by Stitchtenoth, "Algebraic function fields and codes".

I am having some troubles understanding a exact sequence of linear mappings between Riemann-Roch spaces and adeles (pag. 25).

Let $F/K$ be a function field. Let $A_1,A_2$ two divisors on $F$ such that $A_1\leq A_2$. We then have the sequence of linear mappings
$$
0 \to \mathscr{L}(A_2)/\mathscr{L}(A_1) \xrightarrow{\sigma_1} \mathcal{A}_F(A_2)/\mathcal{A}_F(A_1) \xrightarrow{\sigma_2} (\mathcal{A}_F(A_2)+F)/(\mathcal{A}_F(A_1)+F) \to 0.
$$

The book says it is defined in the obvoius manner, but which is the obvious manner of defining this linear maps $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2 $?

Comment: $\sigma_1$ is defined by sending $f\in \mathcal{L}(A_1)$ to its image in each component of the restricted product defining tha adeles.

Comment: And $\sigma_2$ is just the obvious immersion?